# Banks size in 8051

Tags: intel, 8051

I read a book about intel 8051 in which the author says, `8051 has three banks 00h to 1Fh, each bank has 8 registers and each bank is of 8 bytes.` ?

Now I am confused what does he mean by each bank is of 8 bytes when each bank has 8 registers each 8 bytes wide. Kindly guide me

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> bank is of 8 bytes when each bank has 8 registers each 8 bytes wide

A register is 8 *bits* wide, and not 8 *bytes*.

Answer (score 0):

Also, look at the **Chapter 14 Figure 3 Memory Spaces** chart here: (http://www.the8051microcontroller.com/select-figures) 
Hopefully, it will make the picture clearer.

Answer (score 0):

In the 8051, there are **4 bank registers B0 to B3**. Their memory address locations are 
B0 - 00H - 07H
B1 - 08H - 0FH
B2 - 10H - 17H
B3 - 18H - 2FH

The default bank is B0.
Each bank is **8 bytes**. In each bank, there are **8 Registers which are 1 byte each** R0 - R7. Each **register is 1 byte that is 8 bits.**

The banks can be switched by using the PSW (Processor Status Word) Register.
To sum it up, 

Each register is 8 bits(1 byte) R0 - R7
Each bank is 8 bytes B0 - B3